# What happens to a wave when the tube changes in diameter

Tags: waves, acoustics, fourier-transform

everywhere they only show the single diameter tube,
but they don't explain what happens to the wave when
 the tube changes its diameter

Is someone kind enough to graph me how the wave changes when the diameter of the tube changes?

[image]

Comment: What wave are you asking about (in gas, in liquid, in solid)?

Comment: I mean sound waves traveling through an air tube

Comment: OK! Do these waves propagate in a stream or in a stationary gas? Is it acoustic waves or shock waves?

Comment: is acoustic waves

Answer (score 0):

We solve the wave equation in a pipe with a sharp expansion, with the boundary conditions of non-reflection from the right boundary. A periodic signal is set on the left border. The initial data is zero. The animation frames show the passage of a wave through a pipe over 6 periods. We used FEM and Mathematics 12.
[image: Figure 1]